# opencv face detection 2d to 3d

Tags: opencv, coordinates, augmented-reality

I want to convert the detected face rectangle into 3D coordinates. I have the intrinsic parameters of my webcam and my head dimension, how can I determine the depth Z using the projection equation?

x = fx X / Z + u

y = fy Y / Z + v

I understand that fx fy and u v are intrinsic parameters, and that X Y are given by my head dimension, x y are given by the detected face rectangle. It seems that only one equation is enough to determine Z. How to use both of them? Or I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you do not strictly need both of them to compute the depth. However, you may want to use both to improve accuracy.

Another thing to keep in mind is that if your camera is not looking perpendicularly at the planar object (e.g. face) you measured, one or both of the measurements may not be useful to compute the depth. For example if your camera is looking up at a rectangle, only the width will be a good measure for the depth, because the height is compressed by the viewing angle. I don't think this matters for your face detector though, because the proportions of the face are assumed fixed anyway?

Comment: Yes, it is fixed because if the face is not towards the camera, it can't find be detected. My further question is how to use this depth Z to locate the face rectangle in OpenGL 3d Coordinate?I used solvePnP to get the translation matrix, and used it in MODELVIEW. But it was not exactly where I want, though the axes are moving as I move my head. Is there other ways?